# Compress a large data folder(around 1 GB) into 7z format in java

Tags: java, compression

I want to compress large folder to 7z format(because it gives best compression ratios) using java. I used sevenzipbinding.jar, but I could only decompress using it. 
How to compress a folder to 7z format using JAVA?
Any suggestions are welcome..

Comment: Does `sevenzipbinding.jar` not includes its `javadoc`?

Comment: @Rugal that project does not support archive creation.

Comment: You could make you own LZMA version for java

Answer (score 0):

The Inflater/Deflater classes are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) supports 7z format. Here is an [expample](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/examples.html#a7z).